# Why my app shows open ads after closing it

Tags: java, android, admob

I successfully implemented the code from the google developers guide's, but i got two issues on my app, first, when i show the dialog to the user to be sure to close the app, and he closes it, the ad shows, second how can i set up the ad for don't close after my app load completly

this is the guide:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open-ads

and this is my code:
MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static AppOpenManager appOpenManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MobileAds.initialize(
            this,
            new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
            });
    appOpenManager = new AppOpenManager(this);
}
```

OpenAppOpenManager.java

```
public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";
private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
private final MyApplication myApplication;
private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
private Activity currentActivity;
private long loadTime = 0;


/**
 * Constructor
 */
public AppOpenManager(MyApplication myApplication) {
    this.myApplication = myApplication;
    this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

/**
 * Shows the ad if one isn't already showing.
 */
public void showAdIfAvailable() {
    // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
    // and an ad is available.
    if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

        FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                        isShowingAd = false;
                        fetchAd();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        isShowingAd = true;
                    }
                };
        appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
        appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);

    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
        fetchAd();
    }
}

/**
 * LifecycleObserver methods
 */
@OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
    showAdIfAvailable();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
}

/**
 * Request an ad
 */
public void fetchAd() {
    // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
    if (isAdAvailable()) {
        return;
    }

    loadCallback =
            new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull AppOpenAd appOpenAd) {
                    super.onAdLoaded(appOpenAd);
                    AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = appOpenAd;
                    AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "failed to load");
                }

            };
    AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
    AppOpenAd.load(
            myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
            AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
}

/**
 * Creates and returns ad request.
 */
private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
    return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
}

/**
 * Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago.
 */
private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
    long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
    long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
    return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
}

/**
 * Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown.
 */
public boolean isAdAvailable() {
    return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    currentActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    currentActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {

}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    currentActivity = null;
}
```